# prepare Statement in Mysqli with two variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm trying to pass my two variable in prepare Statement,actually i can't pass two variable, my code have a error:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/genre.php on line 4

Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/genre.php on line 9
```

and this is my code:

```
    <?php
include("../db_inc.php");
if($stmt=$connection->prepare("INSERT INTO genre(genre_name,genre_desc) VALUES('?','?')")){
    $stmt->bind_param('sd',$genre_name,$genre_desc);
    $genre_name =$_POST["genre_name"];
    $genre_desc =$_POST['genre_desc'];
    $stmt -> execute();
     $stmt -> close();
     $mysqli -> close();
    }
$result=mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());
if("$result"){
    echo "Add Successfully";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the quotation marks from the values...

```
"INSERT INTO genre(genre_name,genre_desc) VALUES('?','?')"
```

should be...

```
"INSERT INTO genre(genre_name,genre_desc) VALUES(?, ?)"
```

Edit-Edit: Forget this bit... I stand corrected

EDIT: Also...

```
$stmt->bind_param('sd',$genre_name,$genre_desc);
$genre_name =$_POST["genre_name"];
$genre_desc =$_POST['genre_desc'];
```

Should be...

```
$genre_name =$_POST["genre_name"];
$genre_desc =$_POST['genre_desc'];
$stmt->bind_param('sd',$genre_name,$genre_desc);
```

You are declaring the variables after they are used.

Comment: the php manual declares the variables after `bind_param`, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: thanks, but also i see another error `Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/admin/genre.php on line 10` how can i solve that?

Comment: @Gavin I was under the same impression that they should be declared first but just barely checked and that's how it was stated. It works fine either way though it looks like.

Comment: have you declared $mysqli in the include file?

Comment: @MichaelStClair Yeah seems odd but  guess they aren’t bound until the execute and just act as place holders.

Comment: @Radian have you declared $mysqli in the include file? Is the include file successfully loaded?

Comment: in the include file i just load connection information,i'm remove the code `     $stmt -> close();
     $mysqli -> close();` and now that's work,

Comment: @Radian they should be left in and the errors should be corrected. the error is telling you that the $mysqli is not an object. do you declare t in your include file or use a different variable name?

Comment: Nice! you right i'm using different name for the connection,thanks Gavin :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt->bind_param('sd',$genre_name,$genre_desc);
$genre_name =$_POST["genre_name"];
$genre_desc =$_POST['genre_desc'];
```

You have $genre_name as a string, and $genre_desc as a double in your bind param... Are you sure the data passed in $_POST['genre_desc'] is a double and not a string? It looks like your passing a description, which to me would be a string, like so:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$genre_name,$genre_desc);
```

PS: The defining of the variables for the bind_param are fine placed after the bind_param statement! They just must be declared BEFORE the "execute" command for the statement!